# How to get a database value (Lambda Expressions)

Tags: c#, database, lambda

I wanted to get the date of birth that corresponds to id anyone can help me with that?
Thank you

```
public Filho Idade(int id)
        {
            DateTime idade = basedados.Pessoa.Select(Pessoa.Filho.DataNascimento).where(p => p is Filho && p.IdPessoa == id);

            return idade;
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime idade = basedados.Pessoa_Filho
    .Where(p => p.IdPessoa == id)
    .Select(p => p.DataNascimento)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the help but still not working? The "DataNascimento" is "Pessoa" table hierarchy.

Comment: I updated the answer changing the table Pessoa to Pessoa_Filho.  Does that work?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda mas já consegui descobir.

Comment: ``` var IDADE =
                    from p in basedados.Pessoa.OfType<Filho>()
                    where p.IdPessoa == Iidfilho.Value
                    select p.DataNascimento;```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a name for the lambda argument, that argument represent the object `Pessoa` in execution time:

```
//Select return a generic interface IEnumerable
IEnumerable<DateTime> idade = basedados.Pessoa.Select(p => p.Filho.DataNascimento);
```

But if you only need a age of the one person you should use `FirstOrDefault` instead to obtain the person by the ID, and then the age

```
// If you need only date, then change the return type to DateTime instead Filho
public DateTime Idade(int id)
        {
            //First get the person for the age
            Pessoa temp = basedados.Pessoa.FirstOrDefault(p => p is Filho && p.IdPessoa == id);
            //Then get the age of that person, if the person is null return current date
            DateTime idade = temp?.DataNascimento ?? DateTime.Now;

            //Last return the age
            return idade;
        }
```